# Replace AppCompatActivity by Fragment, but not access old class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, appcompatactivity

i try to create BottomBar with this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOVwg3zitwg)

But, i have an existing project, with few class already implement, and when i try to change AppCompatActivity by Fragment, my old method/class are inaccessible

an excract of old class :

```
public class ChoixFormulaire extends Fragment {


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_choix_formulaire,container,false);

        return rootView;
    }

    public void formJ(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(ChoixFormulaire.this,RechercheJournalier.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    public void formP(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(ChoixFormulaire.this,FormulaireRecherche.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    public void retourF(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(ChoixFormulaire.this,RechercheDuJour.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

But, the fort this part :

```
(ChoixFormulaire.this,RechercheJournalier.class);
(ChoixFormulaire.this,FormulaireRecherche.class);
(ChoixFormulaire.this,RechercheDuJour.class);
```

I have this error :

```
"Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(com.appli.cci.ports2a.Recherches.ChoixFormulaire, java.lang.Class<com.appli.cci.ports2a.Recherches.RecherchesJournalier>)'
```

Comment: you can use context of activity to open new activity.

Answer (score 0):

Intents need to be created with the parent activity or the application context.So You need to use your Fragment's Parent Activity Context

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MyClass.class);
```

you need you pass array from first activity like this :-

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArray(key, new String[]{value1, value2});
Intent i=new Intent(context, Class);
i.putExtras(bundle);
```

you can get array from other activity like this

```
Bundle bundle=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] array=bundle.getStringArray(key);
```

Comment: Great this work! But, in an other class i have now :

spinnerArray2 = mA.getSpinnerArray();
            Csa = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.content_spinner, spinnerArray2);
            spin2.setAdapter(Csa);

            idDefaultStr = mA.getIdSpin();
            idDefault = Integer.parseInt(idDefaultStr)-1;

I've an erreor at :

-mA.getSpinnerArray();
- mA.getiDSpin()

Did you know why?

Comment: what is mA there ?

Comment: if you have defined array list in main activity and trying to get in other one this is not the right way to get it.

Answer (score 0):

you are not using context properly check this.

```
 public void formJ(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),RechercheJournalier.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
```

Comment: Great this work! But, in an other class i have now :

spinnerArray2 = mA.getSpinnerArray();
            Csa = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.content_spinner, spinnerArray2);
            spin2.setAdapter(Csa);

            idDefaultStr = mA.getIdSpin();
            idDefault = Integer.parseInt(idDefaultStr)-1;

I've an erreor at :

-mA.getSpinnerArray();
- mA.getiDSpin()

Did you know why?